# what does "for all" mean in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

This is the sentence:

> The enormous room on the ground floor faced towards the north. Cold *for all* the summer beyond the panes, *for all* the tropical heat of the room itself, a harsh thin light glared through the windows, hungrily seeking some draped lay figure, some pallid shape of academic goose-flesh, but finding only the glass and nickel and bleakly shining porcelain of a laboratory.

Well, I  highly think that *for all* in that context is an expression, I'm not sure because I  couldn't understand the meaning of the sentence.

Could you help please ?

Comment: These references might help: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74724/meaning-of-for-all-their-colour , http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for-all-that , http://www.dictionary.com/browse/for--all (scroll down to the bit about idioms and phrases on this page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opening of Aldous Huxley's *Brave New World* has the imagery of a cold place both physically and emotionally.

For all gets used literally, meaning during the entirety (summer) and also to mean "in spite of" (tropical).

> Cold for all the summer

cold during the summer

> *( cold )*  for all the tropical heat of the room itself

figuratively cold even in the presence of (in spite of) tropical heat, both of these descriptions add to the setting of a north (read: cold) facing room.

A very good analysis of the passage can be found [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/qPLdJDKcvG8czs3GNpfwL4/close-reading-brave-new-world-by-aldous-huxley)